# Filtering List as you type jquery jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, filtering

Well my problem would be:

I have a list of persons in jsp, java and jquery, i have 2 inputs name and age that i want to use to filter that list with key ups events.

```
Classes:
Person{ 
 Id id; 
 string age; 
 string others;
 getters and setters
}

Id{
 string name;
 string surname;
 getters and setters
}
```

I would like to get with jquery values from the id:

```
JAVA:
List<Person> list_of_persons; //It has some persons in it
map.put("list", list_of_persons);

HTML:
<% int i = 0; %>
<input type="text" id="filter_name"/>
<input type="text" id="filter_age"/>
<c:forEach items="${map.list}" var="listPerson" id="list_of_persons">
<% i++; %>
<div class="row reg_<%=i%>">

<div class = "col-md-2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="person_name_<%=i%>" 
value="<c:out value="${listPerson.getId().getName()}"/>"/>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="person_age_<%=i%>" 
value="<c:out value="${listPerson.getAge()}"/>"/>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="person_others_<%=i%>" 
value="<c:out value="${listPerson.getOthers()}"/>"/>
</div>
</foreach>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
namekeyupevent(){
  //want to filter the list with the name on keyup

  //Should i compare input name with each object of the list?
  // if so how can i get the name from the list?
  // Something like this would be ok?

   $('.list_of_persons).each(function(){
     var text = $(this).id.name;
}

agekeyupevent(){
  //want to filter the list with the age on keyup
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add class to each input type like age, name and put each iteration in div so that each row can be identified.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="filter_name"/>
<input type="text" id="filter_age"/>
<c:forEach items="${map.list}" var="listPerson" id="list_of_persons">
<div class="record">
<input type="text" class="name form-control" id="person.id" value="<c:out 
       value="${listPerson.getId().getName()}"/>">
<input type="text" class="age form-control" id="person.age" value="<c:out 
       value="${listPerson.getAge()}"/>">
<input type="text" class="other form-control" id="person.others" value="<c:out 
       value="${listPerson.getOthers()}"/>">
</div>
</foreach>
```

jQuery: bind keyup event handler for filter and check if age or name contains value and then show record accordinlgy

```
$(function(){
  $('#filter_name').on('keyup', function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('div.record').hide();//hide all record
      $('div.record').filter(function(){
          return $(this).find('name').val().indexOf(value) !=-1;
      }).show();
  });

  $('#filter_age').on('keyup', function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('div.record').hide();//hide all record
      $('div.record').filter(function(){
          return $(this).find('age').val().indexOf(value) !=-1;
      }).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems right but i have java include on the HTML, inside that <for each> i have 
 <% i++; %>
  that increments the position of the list so the html is painting the list one by one of its objects.

How can i apply your solution to that?

Comment: I know that you are using java with jstl tags, you just need to wrap one more div around three inputs in each row so that i can identify the row. OR you can modify your html and put three inputs in table row.

Comment: Ok, I didn't write it correctly, in my code each input inside the for each is in a <div class="col-md-n">  of bootstrap.

May this be the problem that div.record is not filtering correctly?

At this moment i can get the value and hide al objects from the list. Achieve show the correct matches on the filter is the only thing left to do.

Comment: if you can share generated html from browser viewsource, that could be helpful to look at your issue

Comment: It worked! Thanks, the problem was on the input "class" value, i had class="form-control" instead of class="name form-control" also, there's a mistake, using .text() returns "" using .val() gets the correct value from the input, now everything works properly. 

Thanks for the help.